# Android Runtime Exception while geting json data from web and fill ListView

Tags: android

This is my example code for parsing json data and fill it into list-view,but it's give me a run-time error?How can i set contact name and key into list-view,I want to hide the key,and only view Contact Name to list,but when i click list view i want to get relevant key with that name.

```
package com.example.myjsonsample;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static String url = "http://192.168.1.2/webandroid/datamanip.php?cat=1";

    private static final String TAG_KEY = "key";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_LGTIME = "lgtime";
    JSONArray contacts = null;
    String[] contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        contactList = new String[]{};
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
         new GetContacts(lv).execute();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ListView lv ;
        GetContacts(ListView vl){
            lv =vl;
        }
         @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Showing progress dialog
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();

            }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {

                       JSONArray arrJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    for(int i=0;i<arrJsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject object = arrJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("JSON PARSE",object.getString("key"));
                        Log.d("JSON PARSE",object.getString("name"));
                        Log.d("JSON PARSE",object.getString("lgtime"));
                        contactList[i] =object.getString("name")+"~"+object.getString("key");   
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            //this is the question : how to add my key into list view ? i want to start another activity with that key
            ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_item,contactList);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: there is no need of this line
ListView lv ;
        GetContacts(ListView vl){
            lv =vl;

Comment: So how to pass listview object to fill ?

Answer (score 1):

```
contactList[i] = object.getString("name")+"~"+object.getString("key");
```

You already have a key there inside the contactList.

Set the `onItemClickListener` to the listView and get the row like

```
String value = contactList[position];
String key = values.split("~")[1]; // that is the location of the key after spliting the     string
```

Then pass the key value as an argument to the next activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key",key_value_here);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes my part of question is solve with your answer.but i have some thread exception

Comment: whats the exception ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string in your contactList ( say tempList contains only value ) and at the time of retreival you can retreive it from contactList as index value in both the strings will be same.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
 contactList = new String[]{};  //<<<
```

initialize array with `zero` length but in  `doInBackground` adding more elements. so initialize array with `arrJsonArray.length()` before adding elements as:

```
JSONArray arrJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
contactList = new String[<arrJsonArray.length()];  // initialize here
for(int i=0;i<arrJsonArray.length();i++){
     // your code here....
  }
```

Comment: @Elshan : yes but you are initializing Array with 0 length in onCreate and in  doInBackground trying to add more elements

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K Yes, I got it.Grate!!